# Socket comunication does not work in localhost

Tags: client-server, winsock

Here is my problem, I have made a test application that require using another App for loading a software in a microchip.
My problem is with this loading App. it consist in real of a client that decode a file and a server that send the file to a serial port.

I do not control those application, I didn't developed them, have no access to the source and have no documentation for them (don't ask). Anyway those 2 app communicate with each other using winsocket with a TCP com (I believe, nothing but a strong guess concerning the winsock part, 100% sure about the TCP thought).

Those 2 soft does work on my dev station PC (win 7 64bit) but not on the target PC (win 7 32bit). It simply act as if the server part wasn't launched at all.
I dumped the winsock config from the PC where it work to put it on the PC where it doesn't but it does nothing. I'm a bit lost, I know nothing about socket programing. Any idea why those soft can communicate on a PC and not on another?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I found the solution, since the target PC was not connected to a network, dsn service could not resolve the "localhost" address. I just changed that for "127.0.0.1" and it worked fine. But now since my official entry point on the software does not allows me to specify that I need to add to the doc for using my soft that in order for it to work you first have to check that parameter in the loader soft...